# C++ (de) serializing a vector order of items

Tags: c++, serialization, vector

This probably seems trivial, but I need to make sure.

When serializing to a file an std::vector, and then de-serializing it from disk to memory, is the index of the items in the vector guaranteed to be the same (assuming I have not consciously changed it whilst in memory) ?

Simply put, will

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

always have the items in that order?

I am using [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) for (de)serializing if its of any importance.

Thanks!

PS: Are there any exceptions to the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your serialization. Typically the order of serialization must always be the same for deserialization as everything else would corrupt the stream from which something is deserialized.

In your case you should dive into docs of cereal or ask them whether they guarantee order, but I would expect that the behaviour is consistent.

A possible fallpit might be a map (which you have not mentioned here) as the internal structure of a map is not the order (most of the time) in which the data was added

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting to mention map, although its vectors I'm concerned about. Will drop an email to the author of cereal and see what he/she has to say.

Comment: I emailed one of the authors of the library, and he reassured me that order is preserved. But you're probably right it should depend on the implementation, I just assumed that vectors being continuous in memory should always preserve order.